# Unable to import neo4j database with blueprints

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop

i'm trying to open a neo4j database by using blueprints implementation, but i got the following exceptions:

```
Neo4jGraph graph = new Neo4jGraph("/Users/pipe/Dev/neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01/data/graph.db");
```

this cause

```
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad value '-192M' for setting 'neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory': value does not match expression:\d+[kmgKMG]?
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
... 32 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad value '-192M' for setting 'neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory': value does not match expression:\d+[kmgKMG]?
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:165)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:135)
at org.pipe.java.web.netnografica.persistenza.graphdb.DAONodo.toGraphml(DAONodo.java:204)
at org.pipe.java.web.netnografica.controllo.ControlloGenerale.esportaGraphml(ControlloGenerale.java:133)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
... 33 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad value '-192M' for setting 'neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory': value does not match expression:\d+[kmgKMG]?
at org.neo4j.helpers.Settings$DefaultSetting.apply(Settings.java:782)
at org.neo4j.helpers.Settings$DefaultSetting.apply(Settings.java:702)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSetting$SettingWrapper.apply(GraphDatabaseSetting.java:215)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSetting$SettingWrapper.apply(GraphDatabaseSetting.java:189)
at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.ConfigurationValidator.validate(ConfigurationValidator.java:50)
at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.applyChanges(Config.java:121)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.create(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:339)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:253)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:81)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:63)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:155)
... 44 more
```

there seems to be a need to provide a properties file. Is correct?

*Edited to answer to Michael Hunger:

Well .. I changed the version of blueprints, now is 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT, but nothing changed. So i provided the configs using the map ask asked by the constructor

```
Map<String, String> configurazione = new HashMap<String, String>();
configurazione.put("neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory", "250M");
configurazione.put("neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory", "100M");
configurazione.put("neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory", "3845M");
configurazione.put("neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "350M");
configurazione.put("neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory", "350M");
configurazione.put("neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "769M");
Neo4j2Graph grafo = new Neo4j2Graph("/Users/pipe/Dev/neo4j-community-2.1.0-M01/data/graph.db", configurazione);
```

Now the exception is changed, and i really don't know what is wrong.. I linked in paste bin to report the complete stack.

http://pastebin.com/XpipSysp

at last a NoSuchMethodError is thrown. What am I missing?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which blueprints version are you using? 
Blueprints 2.5-SNAPSHOT is compatible with Neo4j 2.0.0.

Please note there is a separate module for Neo4j 2.0 called blueprints-neo4j2

And the classes are called `Neo4j2Graph` `Neo4j2Vertex` etc.

You should also be able to provide config to the `Neo4j2Graph`.

Comment: Mmm .. in maven there aren't that version. am I wrong? I'll change dep. Thanks!